# How to play an audio file multiple times

Tags: javascript, audio

I want to make a collision sound whenever collision happens in my game. For that, how do I run the audio file multiple times?

Here is an example, where music keeps playing: [Example](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_fps). But how to play small mp3 file multiple times with If condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you alter the collision logic to emit a new flavor of event which you could then capture to trigger play audio call.  Below shows a mock collision which dispatches fresh emit events which are listened to to play audio.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        var sound_on_click = (function() {

            // --- setup audio logic

            var array_audio_files = []; // array to hold list available media filenames

            array_audio_files.push("awesome_blip.mp3");
            array_audio_files.push("smash_crunch.wav");
            array_audio_files.push("wild_screech.wav");

            var play_sound = function (given_index) {

                var cool_tune = new Audio(array_audio_files[given_index]);

                cool_tune.play();
            };

            // --- event emit

            var event_collision = new Event("see_a_collision"); // define new event type

            document.addEventListener("see_a_collision", function(e) { 

                // randomly pick a media file from all available
                var index_media_file = Math.floor(Math.random() * array_audio_files.length);

                console.log("about to play sound ", index_media_file);

                play_sound(index_media_file);
            });


            // --- below is a mock up of some collision condition

            (function mock_collision(){

                document.dispatchEvent(event_collision); // collision happened so emit event

                setTimeout(mock_collision, 2000); // launch every x milliseconds

            }());

        }());

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just put `new Audio('audiofile.mp3').play();` inside the `if` condition that I was using to detect the collision. Actually, I just needed the syntax to play audio file. I would have used your code if there were multiple files that I wanted to play. So I have accepted your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually kind of a big question. I'd suggest using a library.

The Web Audio API is arguably the best way to play audio in your browser. [Here's a good article on how to use it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/). But unfortunately it's not available on every browser yet which means you need some kind of fallback. It's supported in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. IE support is coming but doesn't exist yet.

Here's a library

```
(function(global) {
  var webAudioAPI = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext;

  // To play a sound, simply call audio.playSound(id), where id is
  // one of the keys of the g_sound_files array, e.g. "damage".

  // options:
  //   startedOnTouchCallback: on iOS no sounds can be played unless at least one is first initiated during
  //       a use gesture. If a function is attached here it will be called when that user gesture has happened.
  //       This is useful for situtations where sounds 'should' start right from the beginning
  //       even if the player as not touched the screen. In that case we put up a message, "touch the screen"
  //       and remove that message when we get this callback
  //
  //   callback: called when all the sounds have loaded.
  var AudioManager = function(sounds, options) {
    options = options || {};
    var g_context;
    var g_audioMgr;
    var g_soundBank = {};
    var g_canPlay = false;
    var g_canPlayOgg;
    var g_canPlayMp3;
    var g_canPlayWav;
    var g_canPlayAif;
    var g_createFromFileFn;

    var changeExt = function(filename, ext) {
      return filename.substring(0, filename.length - 3) + ext;
    };

    this.needUserGesture = (function() {
      var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );
      var needUserGesture = iOS;
      return function() {
        return needUserGesture;
      };
    }());

    var WebAudioBuffer = function() {
    };

    WebAudioBuffer.prototype.play = function(opt_when, opt_loop) {
      if (!this.buffer) {
        console.log(this.name, " not loaded");
        return;
      }
      var src = g_context.createBufferSource();
      src.buffer = this.buffer;
      src.loop = opt_loop || false;
      src.connect(g_context.destination);
      if (src.start) {
        src.start(opt_when);
      } else {
        src.noteOn(opt_when);
      }
      return src;
    };

    function WebAudioSound(name, filename, samples, opt_callback) {
      this.name = name;
      var that = this;
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open("GET", filename, true);
      req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      req.onload = function() {
        g_context.decodeAudioData(req.response, function onSuccess(decodedBuffer) {
          // Decoding was successful, do something useful with the audio buffer
          that.buffer = decodedBuffer;
          if (opt_callback) {
            opt_callback(false);
          }
        }, function onFailure() {
           console.error("failed to decoding audio buffer: " + filename);
           if (opt_callback) {
             opt_callback(true);
           }
        });
      }
      req.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
        console.error("failed to load:", filename, " : ", e.target.status);
      }, false);
      req.send();
    }

    WebAudioSound.prototype = new WebAudioBuffer();

    function AudioTagSound(name, filename, samples, opt_callback) {
      this.waiting_on_load = samples;
      this.samples = samples || 1;
      this.name = name;
      this.play_idx = 0;
      this.audio = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
        var audio = new Audio();
        var that = this;
        var checkCallback = function(err) {
          that.waiting_on_load--;
          if (opt_callback) {
            opt_callback(err);
          }
        };
        audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
          checkCallback(false);
        }, false);
        audio.src = filename;
        audio.onerror = function() {
          checkCallback(true);
        };
        audio.load();
        this.audio[i] = audio;
      }
    };

    AudioTagSound.prototype.play = function(opt_when, opt_loop) {
      if (this.waiting_on_load > 0) {
        console.log(this.name, " not loaded");
        return;
      }
      this.play_idx = (this.play_idx + 1) % this.samples;
      var a = this.audio[this.play_idx];
      // console.log(this.name, ":", this.play_idx, ":", a.src);
      var b = new Audio();
      b.src = a.src;
      // TODO: use when
      b.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
        b.play();
        }, false);
      b.load();
    };

    var handleError = function(filename, audio) {
      return function(e) {
        console.error("can't load ", filename);
      }
    };

    this.playSound = function(name, opt_when, opt_loop) {
      if (!g_canPlay)
        return;
      var sound = g_soundBank[name];
      if (!sound) {
        console.error("audio: '" + name + "' not known.");
        return;
      }
      return sound.play(opt_when, opt_loop);
    }.bind(this);

    this.getTime = function() {
      return g_context ? g_context.currentTime : Date.now() * 0.001;
    }.bind(this);

    // on iOS and possibly other devices you can't play any
    // sounds in the browser unless you first play a sound
    // in response to a user gesture. So, make something
    // to respond to a user gesture.
    var setupGesture = function() {
      if (this.needUserGesture()) {
        var count = 0;
        var elem = window;
        var that = this;
        var eventNames = ['touchstart', 'mousedown'];
        var playSoundToStartAudio = function() {
          ++count;
         if (count < 3) {
            // just playing any sound does not seem to work.
            var source = g_context.createOscillator();
            var gain = g_context.createGain();
            source.frequency.value = 440;
            source.connect(gain);
            gain.gain.value = 0;
            gain.connect(g_context.destination);
            if (source.start) {
              source.start(0);
            } else {
              source.noteOn(0);
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
              source.disconnect();
            }, 100);
          }
          if (count == 3) {
            for (var ii = 0; ii < eventNames.length; ++ii) {
              elem.removeEventListener(eventNames[ii], playSoundToStartAudio, false);
            }
            if (options.startedOnTouchCallback) {
              options.startedOnTouchCallback();
            }
          }
        }
        for (var ii = 0; ii < eventNames.length; ++ii) {
          elem.addEventListener(eventNames[ii], playSoundToStartAudio, false);
        }
      }
    }.bind(this);

    this.loadSound = function(soundName, filename, samples, opt_callback) {
      var ext = filename.substring(filename.length - 3);
      if (ext == 'ogg' && !g_canPlayOgg) {
        filename = changeExt(filename, "mp3");
      } else if (ext == 'mp3' && !g_canPlayMp3) {
        filename = changeExt(filename, "ogg");
      }
      var s = new g_createFromFileFn(soundName, filename, samples, opt_callback);
      g_soundBank[soundName] = s;
      return s;
    }.bind(this);

    this.init = function(sounds) {
      var a = new Audio()
      g_canPlayOgg = a.canPlayType("audio/ogg");
      g_canPlayMp3 = a.canPlayType("audio/mp3");
      g_canPlayWav = a.canPlayType("audio/wav");
      g_canPlayAif = a.canPlayType("audio/aif") || a.canPlayType("audio/aiff");
      g_canPlay = g_canPlayOgg || g_canPlayMp3;
      if (!g_canPlay)
        return;

      if (webAudioAPI) {
        console.log("Using Web Audio API");
        g_context = new webAudioAPI();

        if (!g_context.createGain) { g_context.createGain = g_context.createGainNode.bind(g_context); }

        g_createFromFileFn = WebAudioSound;
      } else {
        console.log("Using Audio Tag");
        g_createFromFileFn = AudioTagSound;
      }

      var soundsPending = 1;
      var soundsLoaded = function() {
        --soundsPending;
        if (soundsPending == 0 && options.callback) {
          options.callback();
        }
      };

      if (sounds) {
        Object.keys(sounds).forEach(function(sound) {
          var data = sounds[sound];
          ++soundsPending;
          this.loadSound(sound, data.filename, data.samples, soundsLoaded);
        }.bind(this));
      }

      // so that we generate a callback even if there are no sounds.
      // That way users don't have to restructure their code if they have no sounds or if they
      // disable sounds by passing none in.
      setTimeout(soundsLoaded, 0);

      if (webAudioAPI) {
        setupGesture();
      }
    }.bind(this);
    this.init(sounds);

    this.getSoundIds = function() {
      return Object.keys(g_soundBank);
    };
  };

  AudioManager.hasWebAudio = function() {
    return webAudioAPI !== undefined;
  };

  global.AudioManager = AudioManager;
}(this));
```

[You can DL it here](http://greggman.github.io/doodles/js/audio.js) and there's a live sample here (http://greggman.github.io/doodles/audio.html);

To use this include it with `<script src="audio.js"></script>`.

Then give it a list of sounds like this

```
var audioMgr = new AudioManager({                               
  fire:      { filename: "assets/fire.ogg",      samples: 8, }, 
  explosion: { filename: "assets/explosion.ogg", samples: 6, }, 
  hitshield: { filename: "assets/hitshield.ogg", samples: 6, }, 
  launch:    { filename: "assets/launch.ogg",    samples: 2, }, 
  gameover:  { filename: "assets/gameover.ogg",  samples: 1, }, 
  play:      { filename: "assets/play.ogg",      samples: 1, }, 
});
```

After that you can play sounds with

```
 audioMgr.playSound('explosion');                               
 audioMgr.playSound('fire');
```

etc...

The `samples` is how may of that sound you want to be able to play at the same time. THIS IS NOT NEEDED for any browser that supports the Web Audio API. In other words it's only needed for IE.

Also note Firefox doesn't support MP3s as far as I know so you'll need to supply `.ogg` files for it. Conversely, Safari doesn't support `.ogg`.  The library handles loading `.mp3` or `.ogg` files regardless of what you specify when you init the library. In other words if you put `filename: "foo.mp3"` the library will try to load `foo.mp3` or `foo.ogg` depending on if the browser you're in supports one or the other.